# Consider a general arithmetic sequence,$\{x_n\}^{\infty}_ {n=1}$, deﬁned by $x_n = a+nb$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a general arithmetic sequence,$\{x_n\}^{\infty}_ {n=1}$, deﬁned by $x_n = a+nb$, ($n ≥ 1$).Prove that if $c$ is any integer such that gcd$(b,c) = 1$ then there is some element of the arithmetic sequence that is divisible by $c$. Your solution should provide a clearly deﬁned method for obtaining a location in the sequence where the divisibility happens.

Comment: What did you try doing so far?

Answer (score 1):

If $c|a + nb$, then: $$a + nb \equiv 0 \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } (mod \text{ }c)$$
$$
nb \equiv -a\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } (mod \text{ }c)
$$
As $(b, c)=1$, there exists a multiplicative inverse of $b$ mod $c$. Let's call it $b^{-1}$.
$$n \equiv n·b·b^{-1} \equiv -a·b^{-1}\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } (mod \text{ }c)$$
So all we have to do is compute the multiplicative inverse of $b$ mod $c$ , and find the least of the positive integers that is congruent to $-a·b^{-1}$ mod $c$.

For example, let a=52, b=14 and c=17. Then, we find $b^{-1}$ via the euclidean algorithm:

$$c - b = 17 - 14 = 3$$
$$5b - 4c = b - 4(c - b) = 14 - 4·3 = 2$$
$$5c - 6b = (c - b) - (5b - 4c) = 3 - 2 = 1$$
So the inverse of $b$ is $-6$.

Now, $n \equiv -a·b^{-1} = -52·(-6) \equiv (52 - 17·3)·6 = 6$

This algorithm also shows that the optimal value of $n$ lies between $0$ and $c$